# Upload image from client machine to server

Tags: asp.net

i want to upload image on server whose path is specified in xls file.
i am using upload control to upload that xls file.
xls file structure is as below

ProductName         Price              ImagePath

Product1                 10                c:\product1.jpg

Product2                 10                c:\product2.jpg

Product3                 10                c:\product3.jpg

Product4                 10                c:\product4.jpg

i just want to know that it is possible to upload that image

Answer (score 0):

You would need the software client side because by the time the Excel file gets uploaded it is server side and does NOT have access the the mentioned path within the file.

The web browser will not do this for you. This means you'll need something like ActiveX, Flash  or Java applet and you'd have to upload using that, and write code to read the Excel file as well, get those images and upload them.